# Writing a shader once without using CG?

Tags: shaders, glsl, hlsl

Is there a tool that can convert a fragment shader from hlsl to glsl or glsl to hlsl? I do not want to use cg since it is not able to work on mobile platforms.

Is there a tool that can make it so I only write a shader once?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shiny](https://github.com/scrawl/shiny) is a new library that aims to make material management and portable shader writing easy. This is achieved mostly with a preprocessor meta language, that can output any of CG, HLSL or GLSL. It is currently geared towards usage with Ogre graphics engine, but that part is abstracted into a separate component, so it shouldn't be hard to plug in any other engine. The library has been / is being integrated into [OpenMV](http://openmw.org/en/) and [Stunt Rally](https://code.google.com/p/vdrift-ogre/) (*disclaimer: I'm a member of the latter*).

There is a lengthy introduction [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=71117).

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for either one, but there is a utility available here for going from HLSL to GLSL: https://github.com/aras-p/hlsl2glslfork

and here for going the other direction:
http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/

The first one is explained more here:
http://aras-p.info/blog/2010/05/21/compiling-hlsl-into-glsl-in-2010/

Answer (score 0):

There's the tool MojoShader which accomplishes what you want: http://icculus.org/mojoshader/